# need to open bpopup when an image is clicked

Tags: php, jquery, css, jquery-ui, bpopup

I am trying to open the pop-up when an image is clicked, rather than on button click.
How could it be done?

### Its a gallery kind of thing, where the images are loaded categorically and when clicked on the image, a bpopup show up and the details of the products are shown

I tried that,
Please check the fiddle file http://jsfiddle.net/psps/NhRHC/
The problem that I am facing now is it opens up in the first image click, but not in the second image.

**HTML**

```
<img id="my-button" src="http://placehold.it/200&text=A">
<img id="my-button" src="http://placehold.it/200&text=B"> 
<!-- Element to pop up -->
<div id="element_to_pop_up">
    <a class="b-close">x<a/>
    Some text
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#element_to_pop_up { 
    background-color:#fc0;
    border-radius:15px;
    color:#000;
    display:none; 
    padding:20px;
    min-width:400px;
    min-height: 180px;
}
.b-close{
    cursor:pointer;
    position:absolute;
    right:10px;
    top:5px;
}
```

**JS**
its in that jfiddle link.

Comment: you should put some code. can't answer on you unclear question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using jQuery, you can do it like this -

```
$('#div img').click(function(){ $("#popup").bPopup(); });
```

This statement will make the images in the container element with id "div" open up a bPopup when they are clicked.